# MySQL group_concat + subquery or substring_index

Tags: mysql, sql

Well i got 2 tables:

```
- tb_shops
shop_id PK
shop_name

- tb_products

product_id PL
product_name
shop_id FK
```

I need to list something like:

```
shop_name | product01,product02,product03,product04
shop_name2 | product05,product06,product07,prodcut08
```

but these products need to have a limit 4 per shop.

Well i tried these queries:

Fist with subquery

```
select SQL_NO_CACHE a.shop_id,
        a.shop_name,
        count(b.product_id) as ptotal,
        (select group_concat(_b.product_name separator ',') from tb_shops _a left join tb_products _b using(shop_id) where _a.shop_id=a.shop_id group by _a.shop_id limit 4) as products 
from tb_shops a 
left join tb_products b on a.shop_id=b.shop_id 
group by a.shop_id
order by a.shop_name asc
```

Second with substring_index

```
select SQL_NO_CACHE a.shop_id,
        a.shop_name,
        count(distinct b.product_id) as ptotal,
        substring_index(group_concat(distinct c.product_name separator ','),',',4) as products 
from tb_shops a 
left join tb_products b on a.shop_id=b.shop_id 
left join tb_products c on a.shop_id=c.shop_id 
group by a.shop_id
order by a.shop_name asc
```

which these is better? or someone knows a better solution?

Comment: Do you really need a sub-query? What happens if you just do group_concat in the main query?

Comment: it will return more than 4 products

Comment: i just need to list 4 products per shop

Comment: I see. Sorry, I didn't read carefully enoug. But I guess join version is the better alternative when using MySQL.

Comment: @jarlh, well i don't know cuz imagine a example, if the shop01 has 200 products, all these products will come in this query then it will be split with a string function to 4 items

Comment: if u think in a small quantity of products maybe the join version is better but if u think in many products, it's not better

Comment: @Awsj2hd8 Considering giving feedback on your other answer would help you get people to help.